# Thread synchrnisation with PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream

Tags: java, stream, synchronization, output, pipe

I have a problem when trying to realize thread synchronization with PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream in Java.

There are three threads T1, T2, T3 that can edit a file named toto.txt in concurrence. The file content of toto.txt is something like:

> `T1 : 1 
>   T2 : 1 
>   T3 : 1 
>   T1 : 2 
>   T2 : 2 
>   T3 : 2 
>   T1 : 3 
>   T2 : 3 
>   T3 : 3 
>   ....`

My idea is: each Thread can access to toto.txt only when it have a key variable key = true. After editing file, thread A write key content into a pipedInputStream connected to a PipedOutputStream. Thread B read key from PipedOutStream, if key = true, B can access to edit file. There is a starting thread that can write to file, another thread wait first for the key -> write to file -> write key to pipe. If there are 3 thread, so there are 3 pipe connected: T1-T2, T2-T3, T3-T1.

My code Thread

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class threadFlux implements Runnable {

    public String _threadName;
    public boolean _key;
    public boolean _stratingThread;
    public int _count;
    public int _maxCount;
    public String _fileName;
    public DataInputStream _is;
    public DataOutputStream _os;

    public threadFlux(String threadName, String fileName, boolean starting, int maxCount) {
        this._threadName = threadName; 
        this._maxCount = maxCount;
        this._count = 1;
        this._fileName = fileName;
        this._stratingThread = starting;
        this._key = (starting == true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (this._count <= this._maxCount) {
            if (this._stratingThread == true) {
                try {
                    /* starting thread write to file */
                    System.out.println("startint thread");
                    System.out.println(this._threadName + ": " + this._count);

                    this.writeToFile(this._threadName + ": " + this._count + "\n");
                    this._count++;
                    /* write key to pipe */
                    this.writeKeyToPipe(this._key);
                    System.out.println("key written");
                    /* set key = false */
                    this._key = false;
                    this._stratingThread = false;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(threadFlux.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    /* read key from pipe */
                    System.out.println(this._threadName + " Clef " + this._key);
                    this._key = this.readKeyFromPipe();
                    System.out.println(this._threadName + " Clef " + this._key);
                    /* write key to pipe */
                    System.out.println(this._threadName + ": " + this._count);
                    this.writeToFile(this._threadName + ": " + this._count + "\n");
                    this._count++;

                    /* write key to pipe for another thread */
                    this.writeKeyToPipe(this._key);
                    this._key = false;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(threadFlux.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(this._threadName + " finish!");
    }

    public void setPipedStream(PipedOutputStream pos, PipedInputStream pis) throws IOException {
        this._os = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(pos));
        this._is = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(pis));

    }

    private void writeToFile(String string) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(this._fileName);

        //if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        //true = append file
        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(), true);
        try (BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter)) {
            bufferWritter.write(string);
            bufferWritter.close();
        }
    }

    private void writeKeyToPipe(boolean _key) throws IOException {
        this._os.writeBoolean(_key);      
    }

    private boolean readKeyFromPipe() throws IOException {
        return this._is.readBoolean();
    }
}
```

My main program

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // TODO code application logic here

            threadFlux runnableThread1 = new threadFlux("T1", "toto.txt", true, 3);

            threadFlux runnableThread2 = new threadFlux("T2", "toto.txt", false, 3);

            threadFlux runnableThread3 = new threadFlux("T3", "toto.txt", false, 3);

            PipedOutputStream pos1 = new PipedOutputStream();           
            PipedOutputStream pos2 = new PipedOutputStream();
            PipedOutputStream pos3 = new PipedOutputStream();

            PipedInputStream pis2 = new PipedInputStream(pos1);
            PipedInputStream pis1 = new PipedInputStream(pos3);
            PipedInputStream pis3 = new PipedInputStream(pos2);

            runnableThread1.setPipedStream(pos1, pis1);
            runnableThread2.setPipedStream(pos2, pis2);
            runnableThread3.setPipedStream(pos3, pis3);

            Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnableThread1);
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnableThread2);
            Thread thread3 = new Thread(runnableThread3);

            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();
            thread3.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {        
        }
    }
}
```

The problem when I run those codes that: it's blocked after the starting thread wrote to file and wrote key to PipedOutputStream.

Thanks for any helps

Answer (score 0):

PipedOutputStream has a fixed buffer, 4k last time I looked. When it fills it blocks on write until the reading thread reads something. So your read thread isn't reading.

Don't do this. I/O pipes between threads are basically unnecessary. You don't need to move data like this. Find another design.